# Sitecore Navigation Start Point

Tags: navigation, sitecore, sitecore7

I was wondering if there is a way to set an item as the "navigational starting" point as far as the left-hand nav is concerned.

http://internal.simmons.edu/students/slis

On this page, there is a section for our School of Library and Information Science and the subitems that fall within it. As you can see in the nav, this SLIS section is a subsection to a main "Students" section.

Without moving the SLIS item in tree, is there a way to tell sitecore to set this page/item as the navigation starting point? Basically, I'd like the left-nav to have the "STUDENTS" nav header be replaced with the "Simmons Library and Information Science" and the nav to be only the SLIS navigation.

Is there a built-in setting that allows this (again without moving it in the tree or changing the URL)?

Thanks!

-mike

Comment: As with most things in Sitecore there is a way to achieve what you want. Do you have any code to share? It all depends on how the breadcrumb is being rendered.

Comment: Does the control rendering the nav accept a datasource or is it setup to render down from the homepage?

Comment: As graham says, post up some code, depending on how it's written it could be a fairly small change.

Comment: Thanks all. This all sounds way out of my league haha - but we will be working with some folks that should be able to help us out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

There is no "built-in" functionality for the end website in Sitecore. Anything you see on your website is either custom code, an installed module, or a development accelerator. As such, you can achieve your desired goals by making changes to the definition or logic of the sublayout that renders your navigation.

Likely, you will need to find the ASCX code behind (or XSL rendering, or CSHTML rendering) that handles the navigation output and make the necessary code changes to alter where it considers the 'root' of the tree.

Depending on the requirements, you may need to consider changing the sublayout to be driven by a datasource, and not the current page. This would allow authors to change on any given page the 'root' of the menu. This is recommended if you want to have different root behaviour in different pages, since you cannot write a single algorithm in the code to work everywhere. In that scenario, you would change the code to load the datasource item and use it as the root instead of the current item it is using.